# Is there anywhere I can get (relatively new) stable versions of Dart?

Tags: dart

So I upgraded to 1.4 for a project I am contributing to (in development/testing branch of course) and ran into some problems and thus we want to use Dart 1.3.6 again. However, I cannot find this.

Does anyone know where I could download it?

I have seen and starred https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18323
as I was putting this question together, but of course seems like there is no more movement there just yet.

I think I pretty much ran into similar issues to what corgath described in comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457992/where-can-i-find-previous-older-versions-of-dart)... looking for the right version in those "archives" where the "latest" is not really the latest anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update

There is now a nice page to select and download specific Dart versions https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download-archive/

Since a while there are also `deb` packages available which can be installed using

```
sudo apt-get install dart=1.7.0-dev.0.1.*
```

see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/debian.html for more details.

#### Original

You can download from 
http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/

The list only contains the build number but each folder contains a file `VERSION` that contains detailed version information for this build.

dev channel releases can be found here
http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/dev/release/

there are also unsigned raw builds (bleeding edge) but it is not recommended to use them.
http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-archive/channels/be/raw/release/

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

I do hope someone involved in the relevant areas does get to work on better exposing this info though...:)

Comment: You have seen there was quite some discussion on the issue you linked to but they have an awful lot of tasks with higher priority.

Comment: Oh yea, I understand. It's not too uncommon for documentation and other kinds of user/consumer-aiding things to become like the bastard child, for want of a better term, especially when a project is big and/or complex and has any kind of significant following, etc.

Comment: As far as I have seen they give higher priority to issues that hit more people. I think this is the way to go: make common things easy and unusual things possible. I think docs are quite good for such a young language.

Comment: That sounds good. And to be clear, I wasn't really criticising dart's docs, just speaking generally.

Comment: I know, often it's the way you mentioned, but I think the Dart team sorts the priorities the right way (I have many issues that I liked fixed myself but I agree with low priority when few others suffer the same problem and there is some workaround).